# Check if the files in a specific directory have the proper extension?

Tags: shell-script, grep, find, pipe, for

I have created a script that will create a few directories and then organize other files from one directory by moving them into specific sub-directories based on their extension (i.e. `.gif` in `media`, `.jpg` in `pictures`).

Now I have to check those directories to make sure they contain only those files with the proper extension.

Below is what I've come up with so far with comments explaining where I'm going with this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #iterate over each DIRECTORY once
    #while in DIRECTORY list the files it contains
    #check the extension of containe files with given list of EXTENSIONS
    #if file has wrong extension print error message and stop loop
    #if all files are in corret DIRECTORY print confirmation message

    echo "Checking: $DIRECTORY for:$EXTENSIONS"

    for (( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )); do
        if [[ i -eq 1 ]]; then
            DIRECTORY="documents"
            EXTENSIONS="*.txt *.doc *.docx"
            #list files and check EXTENSIONS
    elif [[ i -eq 2 ]]; then
            DIRECTORY="media"
            EXTENSIONS="*.gif"
            #if I equals 2 then look into media DIRECTORY
            #list files and check EXTENSIONS
    elif [[ i -eq 3 ]]; then
            DIRECTORY="pictures"
            EXTENSIONS="*.jpg *.jpeg"
            #if I quals 3 then look into pictures DIRECTORY
            #list files and check EXTENSIONS
    else
            DIRECTORY="other"
            EXTENSIONS="*"
            #statements
    fi  
    done
```

Comment: Note that file "extensions" don't necessarily mean anything, they're as arbitrary as the rest of the filename.  e.g. a jpeg or text file could be named `foo.gif`.   If you want to be certain that the correct file types are in the correct directories, use `file --mime-type` and test for `image/gif`, `image/jpeg`, `text/plain`, `application/msword` etc.

Comment: Sounds quite like a typical use case for the [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Comment: By the way, your original file organizing script can probably be replaced by a couple `find` commands *similar* to the ones in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just print all the files that don't match your extensions?

```
find documents -type f ! \( -name \*.txt -o -name \*.doc -o -name \*.docx \)
find media     -type f !    -name \*.gif
find pictures  -type f ! \( -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.jpeg \)
```

Why do you need to check `other` at all if anything is allowed in there?

By the way, Unix convention is: *"no output = good news"*.  So the above commands just print files that don't match the extensions specified; if all is well they won't print anything.

---

P.S.: This is a good example of [the evolution of a programmer](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html).  ;)